# Get information relevant to user using LINQ on Object list ( Combined lists )

Tags: list, linq, arraylist, linqpad, tobjectlist

I have a list of photos and a list of Albums. I created one single List of type object to combine them. Now I'm trying to use LINQ so that I can retrieve albums based on userId and the photos contained inside the album.

Could anyone help me in understanding how to retrieve the above?

I'm using LINQPAD in order to do that, so I will attach a photo here.

[image]

Comment: Give us your sample data as text instead of image. Add code [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/) or copy all your code to the post

Comment: @Anonymous could you please elaborate more on what do you mean by sample data? All I want after I combined the 2 lists, to use LINQ and retrieve based on user id E.G 1, all the albums that the specific user is assigned to and the photos inside the albums

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not access the property from `object` type (Unless you use [Reflection to get property value in c#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getvalue?view=netframework-4.8)). So that is the reason why you are getting the error.

If you want to retrieve albums based on userId and the photos contained inside the album, you can use `linq to object` like below

```
var result = (from p in _photos
             join a in _albums on p.AlbumId equals a.Id
             where a.UserId==1
             select new { p.Title, a.Title}).ToList();
// It returns `Anonymous type`
```

You can also create one class to store your value like below

```
public class Result
{
    public string AlbumTitle { get; set; }
    public string PhotoTitle { get; set; }
    public string Photo_ThumbnailUrl { get; set; }
    // Any properties as you wish
}

var result = (from p in _photos
                 join a in _albums on p.AlbumId equals a.Id
                 where a.UserId==1
                 select new Result { PhotoTitle = p.Title, AlbumTitle = a.Title, Photo_ThumbnailUrl = p.ThumbnailUrl}).ToList();
```

Comment: And what is the returning type of this when do execute this query? I`m a little bit confused now

Comment: It returns [`anonymous type c#`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types)

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help @Csibi Norbert

Comment: it helped me understand now what`s going on and how I should approach solving this type of issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a [join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause):

```
var query= from photo in _photos
           join album in _albums on photo.AlbumId equals album.ID
           where album.UserId==1
           select new {album, photo};
```

Comment: And what is the returning type of this when do execute this query? I`m a little bit confused now.

Comment: Yes, is an [anonymous type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types),  if you need to know the type of result you are going to need to define a custom class with the result you're expecting